# Entity Framework map attribute to a new table

Tags: entity-framework

I wanted to know if there is any way to map an attribute such as the phone number from a `User` table and create a new table `PhoneNumber` where the only columns will be the `UserID` which will be the FK and PK for this new table and `Phone` attribute, which is the one I want to get from the `User` table.
The reason I want to do this is to reflect in the database all phone numbers from each users, which can be many per user.

This is how my class looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ProvEvents.Models
{
  [Table("User")]
  public class User
  {
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Key()]
    public int UserID{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string UserName{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [MinLength(8), MaxLength(12)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", 
    ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Phone]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([0-9]{10})$"]
    public string PhoneNumber{ get; set; }
   }
}
```

Comment: *which can be many per user* Looks like you need a `PhoneNumber` entity in a one (user) to many (phonenumber) association. I.e. an `ICollection<PhoneNumber>` rather than a string property.

Comment: @GertArnold Would it make sense to have an entity just for the phone number?, I mean, is it a common practice?

Comment: Sure, why not? Look in any phone directory, for example on your, erm... phone. Maybe you want to add more attributes like mobile, land line, primary, ...

Comment: @GertArnold Ok, I went and did that, thank you so much for your help now and in my previous question. You are my sensei.